# Who or what was #118?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, the-case-of-charles-dexter-ward

I just finished reading H. P. Lovecraft's *The Case of Charles Dexter Ward*. (Spoilers...)

One mystery that remains at the end is who exactly was "number 118" (the powerful being summoned by Dr. Willet which ends up eliminating Orne and Hutchinson and instructing Willet to get rid of Curwen). I read the story in *The Thing on the Doorstep and Other Weird Stories* which is fairly thoroughly commented by S. T. Joshi, however he doesn't address the identity of number 118 at all. I've also tried searching for it online for a bit, but all I'm finding is some inconclusive speculation.

It seems clear that Lovecraft didn't mean for the text to give it away, but **what do we actually know about the identity of 118?** Is there any evidence at all that Lovecraft had a specific person (or being) in mind who he just didn't reveal *or* that he kept it vague without reference to any specific person on purpose? And if it was or may have been a specific person, who is the most likely candidate? Evidence both from inside and outside the text is welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, it's a hallmark of Lovecraft's writing to leave his monsters intentionally vague and mysterious. I haven't read this particular story, but in all the Lovecraft stories I've read (which were all very similar - hence why I stopped bothering to read his stuff), the monster/villain is really horrifying but in such a vague way that it's almost impossible to describe it at all beyond the fact that it's horrifying.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm aware that that's his thing, but in this case 118 isn't actually the "main horror" of the story (but seemingly a good, if somewhat terrifying force) and nothing else is left as vague at the end as this. Either way, I'm just hoping that there's some evidence on whether Lovecraft intended it to be someone specific or not (which he may have since there are several vague hints at a specific identity). In any case, there doesn't seem to be a good authoritative source on this matter yet, and SciFi.SE seems like a good place to try and create such a reference. :)

Comment: In case you've not read it yet, the best of the inconclusive speculation I've read has been: [link](http://www.yog-sothoth.com/topic/785-case-of-charles-dexter-ward-118-spoilers/)